# Is it possible to add some debug output when LWP::UserAgent connected to proxy?

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I have a very simple example Perl script

```
$ cat proxy.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent ();

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->show_progress(1);
$ua->proxy([
    [ 'http' ] => 'http://142.93.46.194:3128/',
]);
$ua->get('http://example.com');
```

which prints following output

```
$ perl proxy.pl 
** GET http://example.com ==> 200 OK
```

Any ready-to-use module which adds to debug output one more string which shows proxy server connection status ?

Comment: What do you mean by "proxy server connection status"? Look at LWP::Protocol::http -> sub request.

Comment: Well, `200 OK` is proxy server connection status. You are connecting to a proxy and asking it to get http://example.com for you, in theory it might not even try to get http://example.com and still return `200 OK` :-)